# What preposition do we use with the adjective 'telling' when it means 'revealing'?

Tags: prepositions, collocation, prepositional-phrases

Example I:

> "How telling this is [**of/about**] the way international
>   students continue to be perceived by their American peers on U.S.
>   campuses?"

Example II:

> "Public opinion is telling [**of/about**] its culture."

What preposition should be used with *telling* in sentences of this kind — *of*, *about*, or neither?

Comment: Should you ever insist on using a preposition and the sentence structure as in the example, then *of* it is. However, rephrasing the sentence is better. As the answers on this page show.

Answer (score 2):

*Telling* in this sense is normally not used with a preposition, because it's an **adjective**.

> Public opinion of its culture is telling.

If you have a sentence like your first one where *telling* can't be used as an adjective like this, it's not a sentence where it would normally be used.

Comment: I can't imagine this is true, as it is often followed by an analysis of what it reveals, which doesn't occur if placed at the end.

Comment: Your *telling analysis of* is OK, but the *of* goes with *analysis*. *Telling is an adjective*. I'll add that.

Comment: I'm not sure I agree with you. One can clearly say: 'Public opinion is telling as regards the matter'. Can one not then continue with 'It is particularly telling about the behaviour of the Minister'? Or would I need to say '... as regards the behaviour of the Minister'?

Answer (score 1):

One can use nothing (possibly best)

> a telling smile

one can use *of* (common)

> a telling analysis of motivation in business.
>
> This is telling of the high-input crop production and high animal density polluting agricultural practices that continue to dominate the European landscape.

or, one can use *about* (though this is the least formal)

> how telling this is about the culture of the US

Answer (score 0):

Whilst I think 'of' or 'about' are both valid, I don't think you necessarily need a preposition. 'Public opinion is telling its culture' sounds quite alright to me.

Edit. I now realise that this answer misunderstands the question.

Comment: And what do you think of example I?

Comment: Though I have been upvoted on this I realise I have misunderstood the question. My example uses 'telling' as a verb. see my comment above to Andrew Leach.

Comment: and here I upvoted it! (before edit)

Comment: Thank you everybody for making the conversation absolutely fruitful!