# Use of [brackets] in quotation: altering a single letter in a direct quote

Tags: quotes, quotations, square-brackets

We know that brackets, [these], are used for altering or adding extra information to a direct quote. For example, from [this answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/2272):

> These are used to indicate that a direct quote has been edited **[or altered]**

I have added extra information in the brackets. I am aware of how to change the capitalization. For example, if I quote something and the first letter is not capitalized and I want to capitalize it, I will enclose the first letter in brackets. Consider that "square brackets used while quoting" is a direct quote and I want to quote it but want to capitalize the first letter

> [S]quare brackets used while quoting

However, what I'm wondering is a bit different.

Here is a direct quote from [this](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/150789/387044) answer:

> Edit. I now realise that this answer misunderstands the question.

If I want to quote it and want to change "realise" to "realize" because I have used "reali**z**e" elsewhere... and I just want to change it (i.e. change a single word internal letter), should I just enclose the *s/z* in brackets or the whole word in brackets:

1. > Edit. I now reali[z]e that this answer misunderstands the question.
2. > Edit. I now [realize] that this answer misunderstands the question.

?

Most of the style guides I read don't mention it:

- https://writingcommons.org/article/inserting-or-altering-words-in-a-direct-quotation/
- https://www.thepunctuationguide.com/brackets.html
- https://www.proofreadnow.com/blog/bid/103697/Using-Brackets-in-Quotations

Comment: It has to be **reali[z]e**; **[realize]** would suggest that you have changed the entire word (say, from *actualise* to *realize*).

Comment: The APA style guide says not to correct English spellings to American or vice versa in quotations, and I believe other sources have similar recommendations. https://blog.apastyle.org/apastyle/2012/10/british-spellings.html

Comment: @Stuart F Thank you. That makes sense, but will of course (as here) at times cut across the 'maintain consistency' injunction. I've long thought it the lesser of two evils, _reali[z]e_ etc being even more jarring.

Comment: If the spelling is wrong, the usual practice is to preserve it and then add *[sic]* to indicate that the error was in the original, not your own typo.